# Theoretical difference between classes and types

Tags: class, object, types, theory

This question has been asked on here a few times, but none of the replies really answered it in the more abstract, theoretical sense that I am looking for.

Most answers are something along the lines of "A class has implementations for methods that its objects can respond to, while a type just specifies *which* methods can be responded to".

Well, this seems kind of like an odd definition to me.  Take ints, floats, and chars in a language like C.  It may never be explicitly located in the code, but there are definitely methods built in to the language for responding to the messages ("plus", "minus", etc.) that these types receive.

And as all interfaces must have methods defined *somewhere*, it seems to me that types are the same thing as classes, except the word "class" carries a mental image of a more substantial programming structure than a "type".

Which leads to me to believe that the drawbacks that apply to any class-based language (the "expression problem" for example) would similarly apply to any language with types (Haskell, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no widely applicable, generally accepted definition of the term "class" that I'm aware of, not even wrt type systems. So your question pretty much depends on the context.

If you are talking about classes in object-oriented languages then the description you quote is relatively accurate. Types are specifications, descriptions (of objects or other values). Classes are implementations, definitions (of object factories).

However, in many OO languages, class definitions also introduce distinct type names, and these type names are often the only means to type objects. That's an unfortunate limitation and conflation of concepts, that also leads to the well-known [confusion of subtyping and inheritance](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~wcook/papers/InheritanceSubtyping90/CookPOPL90.pdf). At least some languages separate these concepts properly, e.g. [Ocaml](http://ocaml.org).

In any case, the reason why the distinction is seemingly at odds with ints and floats in C is simple: those are not objects. Despite what OO ideology tries to preach, not everything is an object, and certainly not in every language.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, a class will often have methods that manipulate the data contained within an instance.  A type will not; it only is meant to hold and return data.

Although it is true that there may be methods specified somewhere for the type, there will only be one way to change the data contained within an instance of a type - storing a new value in it.  The methods are generally along the lines of presenting the data in different ways, instead of actually manipulating the data.

This rule can, of course, be broken; C is full of examples, due to how it is structured (or, rather, not structured).  Generally speaking, though, you don't want to have a type with a function that does fancy logic internally.

Comment: That does not make sense. Of course, types can describe operations, and often do. For example, consider structural object types.

Answer (score 0):

"Class" and "type" mean different things in different languages and environments; I will try to show here a synthesis that helps me think about the issue.

Classes have objects, and types have values. I think it is easier to understand the difference between objects and values, than between classes and types. An object has 2 independent properties: its identity, and its state/behaviour. So, you can have two different objects with the same class and state. This is not true for values: you cannot have 2 different values of a type that have the exact same state (or form, shape) and behaviour: you cannot have 2 "twoes". A value of a type does not have an identity independent of its state and behaviour.

Mixing both concepts together, you might say that a value of a given type does not necessarily have a class, but an object of a given class necessarily has a type, (e.g. object), and its value is given both by its state/beheviour and by its identity.

Haskell has types, and definable ones if I am correct. It is from Haskell that I am taking the "type" concept I am using. Python has classes and types mixed into the same "type" system, with some primitive types and rich definable classes. The concept of object that I am using is that of the type system of Python, minus its primitive types: int, str, etc.

Another key difference between types and classes would be in their definition. Types are tipically defined by a set of predicates or constraints that "give" all at once all of the values of the type. Therefore, you can use a literal value without first having to "create" it: 23438573. The definition of a class involves a procedure to create objects, and all objects of that class must be created before they are used.